# Need help implementing ggplot2 tooltip

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have been looking at solutions online for implementing tooltips on a ggplot2 line chart I have created, but have not had any luck.

My R code is the following:

```
library("ggplot2")
ggplot(dataset)


dataset$'Option' <- factor(dataset$'Option', levels = dataset$'Option')

gg <- ggplot(dataset, aes(y=ToNum, x= Option, group = 1)) + geom_line(color='red') + coord_flip() + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 5, by = 0.5)) +  
          theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
                     axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                     axis.text= element_text(size=16),
                     plot.title = element_text(size=20),
                     aspect.ratio=16/9) + 
          ggtitle("Delivering Value") + 
          scale_x_discrete(limits = rev(levels(dataset$'Option')))

print(gg)
```

I am trying to display the values for "ToNum" in the tooltip.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: maybe the plotly package?

Comment: ggplot2 has no inherent "tooltip" concept. where did you get the idea that it did?

Comment: I know it does not, hence the question. If it were inherently built in I probably would not have needed to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `ggiraph`:

```
library(ggiraph)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)

rownames_to_column(mtcars, "car") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(wt, mpg, tooltip=car)) + 
  geom_point_interactive() -> gg

ggiraph(code = print(gg))
```

(it needs to be in an interactive context to demonstrate, hence no image)